# Can complex numbers be visualized

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> If $z=|x+iy|$ is a complex number satisfying $\;|z-2|-|z-3i|=\sqrt5\;$ then locus of $z$ is $\dots$

On solving this I easily get an equation of part of hyberbola.
My question is: Is there any general result for locus problems like $(x-a)^2-(y-b)^2=c$ is a general equation of hyperbola and can be visualized easily?

Is there any sort of visualization for complex numbers?

Comment: To learn more on the subject, google  "complex numbers and geometry", there exist excellent books, chapters etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Represent $x+iy$ as [the point $(x,\,y)$ in the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane#Argand_diagram), so the question is which points are $\sqrt{5}$ more distant (in an additive rather than multiplicative sense) from $2$ than from $3i$. That "the points $\ell$ more distant from $p_1$ than from $p_2$" defines a hyperbola for $\ell>0$ is a theorem of Euclidean geometry in $\Bbb R^2$. Hyperbolae are $e>1$ conic sections; $e<1$ conic sections (ellipses) are the locus of points whose *sums* of distances to some $p_1,\,p_2$ are some $\ell>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, $|z_1-z_2|$ is the distance between points which represent complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2.$

Set the points $M(z),A(2),B(3i).$ The number $z$ satisfies $$|z-2|-|z-3i|=\sqrt5$$ if and only if the difference of distances $$|MA|-|MB|=\sqrt5.$$
This is equation of one branch of hyperbola with foci $A$ and $B.$ The branch is that which is near the focus $B(3i).$

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad xD

Answer (score 0):

Just a little algebra work.
$$
|x-2+iy|-\left| x+\left( y-3 \right) i \right|=\sqrt{5}
\\
\sqrt{\left( x-2 \right) ^2+y^2}-\sqrt{x^2+\left( y-3 \right) ^2}=\sqrt{5}
\\
\left( x-2 \right) ^2+y^2+x^2+\left( y-3 \right) ^2-2\sqrt{\left( x-2 \right) ^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+\left( y-3 \right) ^2}=5
\\
\left( x-2 \right) ^2+y^2+x^2+\left( y-3 \right) ^2-5=2\sqrt{\left( x-2 \right) ^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+\left( y-3 \right) ^2}
\\
\left( \left( x-2 \right) ^2+y^2+x^2+\left( y-3 \right) ^2-5 \right) ^2=4\left( \left( x-2 \right) ^2+y^2 \right) \left( x^2+\left( y-3 \right) ^2 \right) 
\\
-4x^2-48xy+80x+16y^2-80=0
\\
x^2+12xy-20x-4y^2+20=0
$$
Thus the visualized curve (of this complex equation) on $\mathbb R^2$ is $x^2+12xy-20x-4y^2+20=0$.

Then can you continue from here?

*Hint*. $$-4\left( y-\frac{3}{2}x \right) ^2+10\left( x-1 \right) ^2=-10
$$
and substitue $t=y-\dfrac{3}{2}x$.